Physicalists consider virtual reality generated in our brains a science. But is it?
What makes scientific facts about intelligent consciousness generated by our brains more prudent physics than virtual reality generated by supercomputers (Simulation Hypothesis)?
In my view, we equally cannot explain or reproduce both of these realities. Except that a Simulation Hypothesis is a new kid on the block and can be dismissed as non-science.

Kant therefore allows that there is ‘sensible intuition’, a faculty of
sensibility and that this comes from us: the outer senses create
spatial boundaries, the inner sense equals time. Kant also maintains
that there is no empirical knowledge without the prior activation of
sensible intuitions. But, a big BUT, the Copernican revolution demands
that we reject a priori knowledge of transcendent worldly objects. Why
does Kant deny that we are capable of, what he elsewhere calls,
intellectual intuition?
The clue for understanding this, and attaining a fuller sense of
Kant’s Copernican Revolution, can - I think - be found in Kant’s
notion that while sensible intuition is derivative (intuitus
derivatus), intellectual intuition is original (urspruenglich:
‘originary’ -or, in Kant’s Latin phrase intuitus originarius). That
is, intellectual intuition originates or creates its objects, as
opposed to sensible intuition which only receives known objects.
This means that, according to Kant, only the “primordial being”
(Urwesen) is capable of having intellectual intuition (On this point
cf. CPR B68-72) God’s intellect, in other words, is an intellectus
archetypus whereas our minds are mere intellectus ectypus.
https://www.quora.com/What-is-Kants-Copernican-Revolution

What Kant is saying is that our brains can generate an infinite number of realities (versions of computer games) that can be similar or distinct or outright weird. But in all of this personal cacophony of images (generated by our brain) there are reflection shadows of something real (primordial). And this "real" part is transcendent to human brains as we know. I think Hegel's "Absolute Truth" talks about the same concept.

Can you name one physicalist that considers "virtual reality generated in our brains" a science (in those words)? Consciousness is not virtual reality. And the simulation hypothesis is not science because it explains no evidence and contains no testable predictions. Whereas psychology and neuroscience (the sciences studying the brain) explains plenty and contains predictions that are not only theoretically testable, but are actually tested all the time.

I cannot even figure out what the claim is. Isn't generating "virtual reality" on computers exactly "explaining and reproducing" it? And what are "scientific facts about intelligent consciousness generated by our brains" supposed to be? Much of what our brains generate, especially as it concerns "intelligence", is being "explained and reproduced" by AI and accompanying neuronet models. "Consciousness" is a big umbrella, and much of it is not as mysterious as phenomenal first person effects, see Higher-Order Theories of Consciousness.

You may not realize it but I believe you've stumbled upon Kant's Copernican revolution. I particularly recommend the answer by Blaisse Tassone for delineating how Kant clarifies and corrects Plato

I think you may find the book Tertium Organum useful. The first chapter is pure Kant. The second onwards deepens the study

While I dont agree with the closure, I do think you should pay more heed to @Lowri suggestions.  If you do, you will find your questions get closed less (or at least less fast!)

Re. "Kant is saying is that our brains can generate an infinite number of realities... [In this] ... cacophony of images ... there are reflection shadows of something real" — I.e. "the entire storehouse of material from which all possible predicates of things can be taken, then this substratum is nothing other than the idea of an All of reality (omnitudo realitatis)." B603 — My take is these are all the possibilites of the moment. Not until I look & check is the actuality revealed, but that is not transcendental.

You say:

Physicalists consider virtual reality generated in our brains a science.

No. Physicalists don't consider events or entities to be "a science." Rather, science is a social practice and method of refining our beliefs.
Then you ask:

What makes scientific facts about intelligent consciousness generated by our brains more prudent physics than virtual reality generated by supercomputers (Simulation Hypothesis)?

Breaking this down:

The sentence structure is "What makes scientific facts ... more prudent physics...?"
But facts are not physics. So, nothing makes scientific facts about anything more prudent physics than anything else. You're making a category error by trying to compare these things in this way.

You then go on to say a lot of things about your own beliefs and those of a user on Quora regarding Kant, but you haven't asked anything about that material. It seems that portion should be part of a self-answer to your question, if anything.

OP: "Physicalists consider virtual reality generated in our brains a science. But is it?"
Since experience is one's starting point from which observations can be made about the world, the "virtual reality" is rather the outside world, which, so far as we know is fundamentally made of such things as quarks and photons which we "cannot explain" except by descriptions of observations.

Taken superficially, the term "phenomenology" is formed like
"theology", "biology", "sociology"—names which may be translated as
"science of God", "science of life", "science of society". This would
make pheno­menology the science of phenomena. GA2
p.50

Dasein—the observer of phenomena—bears the light that illuminates reality.

whenever an ontology takes for its theme entities whose character of
Being is other than that of Dasein, it has its own foundation and
motivation in Dasein's own ontical structure, in which a
pre-ontological understanding of Being is comprised as a definite
characteristic.
Therefore fundamental ontology, from which alone all other
ontologies can take their rise, must be sought in the existential
analytic of Dasein.
Dasein accordingly takes priority over all other entities in several
ways. The first priority is an ontical one: Dasein is an entity
whose Being has the determinate character of existence. GA2
p.33–34

So experience is the primary phenomenon that opens up the world to experience. The world thus revealed is a synthesis of observations and scientific descriptions. An objective computer-generated virtual reality would be in the objective world, along with quarks, houses and planets.
The difference between experience and an objective simulation is that Dasein actually is its experience.  Even physicalists have to address the ontological foundations of the physical entities they observe, and although experience is too varied and indefinite to be determined scientifically it can be understood as experience (from its "pre-ontological understanding").
OP: “What makes scientific facts about intelligent consciousness generated by our brains more prudent physics than virtual reality generated by supercomputers (Simulation Hypothesis)?”
Consciousness is what generates scientific facts in the first place. If it were itself a simulation it wouldn’t make any difference to one’s understanding of experience. Certainly some biological facts about brain functioning are known, but not so much facts about higher functioning of experience, e.g. possibly via Orch OR or mechanisms as yet unknown to science, which is the level at which ‘simulation’ could be operational.
In the sense of 'simulation' as copy or imitation the word is not appropriate for experience. Experience always has an edge of second-guessing, assuming various origins like evolution. If instead experience is due to a more convoluted path it is still experience and not a simulation of the initial, simpler, imagined path (which never was). So experience can never be a simulation.
What make the usual scientific view about "intelligent consciousness generated by our brains" more 'prudent' is basically Occam's Razor aiming to take the simplest path.


The simulation hypothesis makes the assumption that our world and
also we humans are a programm running on a computer.
While a conservative approach considers each human to be a separate
system with a brain of its own. The brain creates processes which the
system experiences as conscious. The brain and its processes
developed during the phylogenesis of the evolution and the
ontogenesis of socialization in adaption to our environment.


These two points of view differ in the mechanism underlying each of
the two processes: On one hand, the simulation hypothesis assumes,
that one specific developer designed the program, which controls the
process. On the other hand, the theory of evolution operates with
self-organisation and lacks any prior design.
The simulation hypothesis follows a teleological principle, while the evolution theory dismisses any teleology.

The theory of biological evolution and the mechanisms of socialization have been scientifically studied and confirmed in many cases.
The simulation hypothesis has the status of an interesting but unconfirmed speculation.



Very slight clarification: the simulation doesn't have to be running on a digital computer. It could be an analog system, which would make finding artifacts much more difficult. But until there is some reason to believe it, or some consequence of believing it, it's somewhat orthogonal to other philosophy.

@keshlam You are right. Thanks, I made a correction.
